# How does gschem name nets?

Tags: geda

I don't understand how to name a net made up of several segments all at the same time.

gEDA gschem [documentation](http://wiki.geda-project.org/geda:gschem_ug:pins_nets_buses) says: *"Nets are made up of straight net segments..."*

I have the next net:

[image]

My questions:

1. Why, when I double-click on an arbitrary net segment, the net is selected completely (that's good), the window for "Edit Attributes" appears (also good), but it's inactive and it's impossible to add netname attribute:

[image]

2. If I select all net segments and do right click and select "Add attribute.."

[image]

and set netname attribute say to NET1 - gschem names every segment separately.

[image]

3. Moreover - I can name connected segments separately:

[image]

Why? Is it usefull somehow ?

Is it possible to make gschem think that all connected segments are one net, and work with the net as a whole?

Comment: Maybe it needs to be connected to an element, first, so that the SPICE netlist contains an actual net/node. It ma be that only one element is needed, since that will make the netlist show the element connected and, thus, you have a net.

Comment: unfortunately no - with connected elements  all the same

Comment: Well, it might be worth asking them, directly, then.

Answer (score 0):

I've understand by myself. It's sufficient to name only one segment of the net. All components connected to other "unnamed" segments will be connected to named net by **gnetlist**.